# Sorting selectbox with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting

I'm Setup a `<select>` dropdown list and I trying to make options sorting in numerical order (Ascending) :

**HTML**

```
<select id="singleSelector">
    <option value="/single?id=544">1</option>
    <option value="/single?id=598">4</option>
    <option value="/single?id=605">6</option>
    <option value="/single?id=604">3</option>
    <option value="/single?id=603">7</option>
    <option value="/single?id=602">5</option>
    <option value="/single?id=601">2</option>
</select>
```

Edit :
When using the following JS by @Sanjay, the order is not correct :

**JavaScript :**

```
$(function() {
  // choose target dropdown
  var select = $('select');
  select.html(select.find('option').sort(function(x, y) {
    // to change to descending order switch "<" for ">"
    return $(x).text() > $(y).text() ? 1 : -1;
  }));
});
```

**Output :**

[image]

It's possible to make order 1,2,3,4,5 instead of 1,10,11...,2,20,21 ?

Comment: Please go read [ask]. This site is not a code-writing service, where all you have to do is drop off your requirement.

Comment: Are these `option` elements created dynamically? If yes, then just sort the data before creating the `option` elements.

Comment: If sorting your data before it is displayed is not an option, you will have to use the onload function to run a custom function once the page has loaded. In that function you will have to find the select element based on its id, extract its options, sort them, and insert them again into the element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is working example.

```js
    $(function() {
  var select = $('select');
  select.html(select.find('option').sort(function(x, y) {
    var num1 = parseInt($(x).text());
    var num2 = parseInt($(y).text());
        return num1> num2 ? 1 : -1;
  }));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
  <select>
    <option selected>Choose a number</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="0">0</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: when it is a numbers that exceeds two digits, the order is not correct. Screenshot : https://i.stack.imgur.com/baIoB.png

Answer (score 0):

try THIS

```
var target = document.getElementById('singleSelector');

function sortIt(target ) {
    var tmp = new Array();
    for (var i=0;i<target.options.length;i++) {
        tmp[i] = new Array();
        tmp[i][0] = target.options[i].text;
        tmpA[i][1] = target.options[i].value;
    }
    tmp.sort();
    while (target.options.length > 0) {
        target.options[0] = null;
    }
    for (var i=0;i<tmp.length;i++) {
        var op = new Option(tmp[i][0], tmp[i][1]);
        target.options[i] = op;
    }
    return;
```